# Making a Valid Analysis with a Convenience Sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, anomaly-detection

I am interested in doing an analysis on the thickness of a particular coin. There are inexpensive forgeries of the coin, and the market is flooded with these forgeries, but one can occasionally find real examples mixed in as well. All the fake samples have a particular thickness $t$. The thickness of the genuine examples varies, but it can be $t$. I am bound by what I can find and what I can afford to acquire (including some certified genuine examples), so my sample is not a random sample by any means. How can I do valid analyses (say, gaussian mixture modeling) on this kind of data, or is it impossible?

Comment: I would recommend in addition to the thickness t metric, that to assess whether a coin is real (assuming the coins of interest are recently issued by a government authority) to apply a simply galvanic corrosion test (coin in aqueous Chlorine bleach  + activated carbon + microwave for a minute or less). Government work hard to develop alloys that are corrosive resistance (as it impacts lifetime of the coin in circulation) while fake coin makers don't care.

Comment: Thanks. You’re assuming the coins were produced recently, but they could be Roman coins, going back to a very long time ago. My question is not so much about the analysis of coins, but more about the fact that there are times that a convenience sample is the only thing available. Are there any tools available to make drawing inferences from such samples valid, or is it completely hopeless